# JavaScript - why does this code log 'undefined' but show up in Chrome Console? (closures)

Tags: javascript, closures

I made this example:

```
(function(_stack_){
  var stack = {
    over: 'flow',
    run: function(){
      console.log(this);
    }
  };
  _stack_.app = stack;
  stack.run();
})(this);

app.foo = 'bar';
```

Output in Chrome console:

[image]

But how come the output of this:

```
(function(_stack_){
  var stack = {
    over: 'flow',
    run: function(){
      console.log(this.foo); // undefined
    }
  };
  _stack_.app = stack;
  stack.run();
})(this);

app.foo = 'bar';
```

Equals `undefined`, while it shows up in the Chrome console?

Check out the **[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/AvewENuq/6/edit?js)**

EDIT:
I understand that it becomes undefined because `stack.run()` is called before `app.foo` is assigned. The question is how come it shows up in the console?

Comment: It does return `bar` on the js bin you gave on chrome 31.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this.foo isn't available at the time you run it

This is poor design, when using javascript like this you probably have more use of a custom constructor function and eventhandling. Your code and question suggests that the run method should be executed at the time you update the dynamically created variable `app`. That will never happened unless you implement some eventhandling for this.

Your code does however work if you call `app.run();` after you set the app.foo variable.

```
// Antipattern ahead!
(function(_stack_){
  var stack = {
    over: 'flow',
    run: function(){
      // Prevent error messages
      if(typeof this.foo === 'undefined') {
          return;
      }
      console.log("log: " + this.foo); // undefined
    }
  };
  _stack_.app = stack;
})(this);

app.foo = 'bar';
app.run(); // log: bar
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because `stack.run()` is executed before the creation of the foo property on the app object.

By the time you're looking in the debugger, the foo property has been created.